# Weighted pairwise distance on categorical data

Tags: r, distance

I have data on concentration values for each sample. These data are ordinal, not continuous, as they have a specific set of possible values, like this:

```
          Compound A     Compound B
Sample 1  0.5            0.25
Sample 2  1              0.12
```

Where compound A can be:

`0.015, 0.03, 0.06, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16`

And compound B can be:

`0.12, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, or 4`

In total I have 13 different compounds. I want to calculate the weighted pairwise distance between the samples based on these 13 different values, where a value of 0.5 is regarded as closer to 1 or 0.25 than 2 or 4 etc.

I am unsure which distance method to use, as there are so many to choose from, and how to implement the weighted distance. Any suggestions as to how to implement this in R?

Here is some example data:

```
structure(list(sample_id = structure(1:7, .Label = c("S1", "S2", 
"S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7"), class = "factor"), comp_1 = c(0.5, 
1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.015), comp_2 = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.25, 0.12, 
0.5, 2, 0.5), comp_3 = c(16, 32, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 1024), 
    comp_4 = c(0.015, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.12, 0.12, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Are they ordinal? They look like interval albeit discrete.

Comment: @ttnphns one could argue that they are, but I would like the distance measurement to treat the values as closer or further apart. Otherwise it will not differentiate between the distance between 0.5 and 1 vs 0.5 and 0.015

Comment: Your right, sure. But ordinal scale removes any values unique, unequal gaps. Consider also other approach, for example log-transforming your scale. Your values below 1 will be negative and well spaced, and above 1 will be positive and samely well spaced.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for the suggestion. How would you proceed with the distance measurement after log-transforming the data? Just treat it as a regular numeric variable with f.ex. euclidean distance?

Comment: There is a great number of distance measures for interval data, not only euclidean d.